# Smooth Javascript animation with StackBlur

Tags: javascript, animation, blur

http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html

If I move the slider on this page, the blurring is very smooth.

But if I try and automate the animation:

```
var speed = 1250;
var blur = 100;
var interval = speed/blur;

setInterval(function(){
  blur--;
  stackBlurImage(image, canvas, blur);
}, interval);
```

The steps are very obvious and it doesn't even work at high speed.

Could anyone suggest an alternative approach to this?

Comment: The render speed is also dependent on the size of the image - is the image you are testing with considerably bigger as the one in my demo?

Comment: @Tom it would be good to mark the answer as correct, or provide more feedback at least since someone has taken their time to give an elaborate answer like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pre-render the different blur levels, store them and cycle through them as frames. Its possible that whatever `stackBlurImage` does just can't be done fast enough to look like an animation.

**Edit:** I take that back, exactly what you did: http://jsfiddle.net/nwellcome/27QUM/ that looks great to me in Chrome, what browser are you using?

**Edit 2:** Try the second approach in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwellcome/27QUM/4/, rather than decreasing the blur radius by 1 each time, fix the fps at something `setInterval` can handle and manipulate the amount you decrease the blur radius each frame.

```
var fps = 30;
var blur = 100;
var blurTime = 0.5; // seconds
var interval = 1000 / fps; 
var step = blur/ (fps * blurTime);

var anim = setInterval(function(){
    blur-= step;
    if (blur < 0) {
        clearInterval(anim);
    }
    stackBlurImage(image, canvas, blur);
}, interval);
```

**Edit 3:** just for the fun of it, with the HTML5 file API, you can upload your own image to blur: http://jsfiddle.net/nwellcome/27QUM/12/

Comment: But it does do it fast enough on the link, drag the slider and see how smooth it is. The problem is elsewhere, setInterval perhaps. I remember reading that in practice there is an artificial minimum limit on the interval time in most browsers.

Comment: There is and setInterval is not given a super-high priority so it won't always be smooth if other things are going on, but if you look at my jsFiddle in Chrome at least it looks really good.

Comment: Another solution above: manipulate how much you decrease the blur radius each frame rather than the interval time.